# Azure DevOps - pip ValueError: HTML doctype missing or incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, pip

I have created a package feed in Azure DevOps. Everything was working until pip version 22.0 was released.

Now when I try to install package from this feed using pip==22.0

```
  File "c:\git_aures_aps\projects\venvs\aures_tools_test_p\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 427, in _raise_error
    "HTML doctype missing or incorrect. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>.\n\n"
ValueError: HTML doctype missing or incorrect. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>.
```

When I have checked https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../_packaging/.../pypi/simple/my-package/ I have found that the website doesn't start with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

[image]

How can I edit / recreate, pypi/simple/my-package repository with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at the rest of the error message.

```
ValueError: HTML doctype missing or incorrect. Expected <!DOCTYPE html>.

If you believe this error to be incorrect, try passing the command line option --use-deprecated=html5lib and please leave a comment on the pip issue at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10825.
```

It takes you to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10825, which has relevant guidance and information. It also notes that you can pass `--use-deprecated=html5lib` to pip, to make it work with this page for now.

As for Azure, you're going to need to reach out to Azure support in all likelihood, since they need to fix this on their end IIUC.

Comment: Thanks for update. With `pip>=22.0.2` no more issues. In 22.0.1 they have fixed not working switch. (oktep)

Answer (score 0):

You can not change it yourself unfortunately, the Azure DevOps team at Microsoft has to do it on their end. There is an open request on Developer Community, where the engineering team is already looking into it, so follow up here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-artifacts-pypi-feed-index-misses-html-doctyp/1667879

For now, you may pass `--use-deprecated=html5lib` until pip 22.2 (i.e. start of Q3 2022), when this flag will be dropped, as stated in the link by pradyunsg.

Comment: Already solved. Issue was just for pip==22.0.0 where flag `--use-deprecated=html5lib` was not working ( this was fixed with version 22.0.1).

Comment: Yes for now, but if MS does not solve it before pip > 22.2 then this will become relevant. But maybe that is a problem for another time...

Comment: you are right. I hope this 9M ultimate period will forced them to do it right!